# Strapi: query rooms with and without user ID

Tags: javascript, strapi

I want to return some default data along with the authenticated data. So basically I have a table called rooms with two columns user and owner_id with relation to another table. I have a few data which does not have any owner_id associated with it. Those are my default data and I want to always send them and then from within my app I can create custom room which will have owner_id associated with it and for those I want to return only the authenticated users data along with the default one. But my problem is either I can send only the authenticated data or all of the data from default to all authenticated users data. Giving the code and screenshots please help.

```
async find(ctx) {
const owner_id = ctx.state.user.id;

const dname = await strapi.services.rooms.find();

const name = await strapi.services.rooms.find({owner_id})
return sanitizeEntity(name, { model: strapi.models.rooms });},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `PostGreSQL` with `strapi`, you can easily fetch the rooms which have owner linked and the default by using `strapi.query` instead of `strapi.services`

```js
async find(ctx) {
    const resp = await strapi
        .query('rooms')
        .model.query(function (qb) {
            if (ctx.state.user) qb.where('owner_id', ctx.state.user.id);
            qb.orWhere('owner_id', null);
        })
        .fetchAll();
    const data = resp.toJSON();
    return data
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. This does return the authenticated users data which I was getting by using services. But still not getting those default data which has no owner_id associated with them.

Comment: Okay, please do a plain find() and check what is the value of owner id in db for default  rooms.. is it 0? or is it null?

Comment: It is null for default. {owner_id: null} -> for default and for authenticated users  owner_id: {
      id: 1,
      username: 'sam',
      email: 'sam@g.com',
      provider: 'local',
      password: '$2a$10$w0ER5k12jWOPqCT0UtPhUOX69H8JASSHrj3i3.A7DmH3/NnCa3ktW',
      resetPasswordToken: null,
      confirmationToken: null,
      confirmed: true,
      blocked: false,
      role: 1,
      created_by: 1,
      updated_by: 1,
      created_at: 2021-08-06T11:28:08.382Z,
      updated_at: 2021-08-06T11:28:08.388Z
    }

Comment: can you try changing the line from `const owner_ids = [ 0 ];` to `const owner_ids = [ null ];`? if not try `const owner_ids = [ false ];` I've already mentioned this in my answer actually.

Comment: It is same for 0, null and false.

Comment: Which service are you using for db? PostGreSQL? or MongoDB?

Comment: PostGreSQL, okay when I change find({'owner_id_in': false/0}); it doesn't return anything only for null it returns all the values. Is it possible to get those data which only has owner_ids = null?

Comment: @RaiyanKhalilShuvo updated my answer. Should work fine now.

Comment: @RaiyanKhalilShuvo please up vote the answer so that it may help others in future.